# How to access a form control value inside a form array: Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form array within a form group. I am trying to access the value of a form control in that form array. When I am trying to access the control getting an error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'`.

I am trying to access the control like this `{{ employmentControls[index]['controls'].designation}}`. I googled and tried a few things to fix the type error but no luck. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

HTML -

```
<form [formGroup]="employmentForm">
   <ng-container formArrayName="employments">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="
            let employment of employments.controls;
            let index = index
        "
      >
            <div [formGroupName]="index" style="margin-bottom: 100px">
                 <div>
                     {{ employmentControls[index]['controls'].designation}}
                 </div>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
initEmploymentForm(): void {
    this.employmentForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        employments: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
}

get employments(): FormArray {
    return this.employmentForm.get('employments') as FormArray;
}

get employmentControls(): AbstractControl<FromGroup>[] {
    return (this.employmentForm.get('employments') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using Angular 14 with [the reactive form is strictly typed by default](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms).

You can use [`.get()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) to get the form control as below:

```
{{ employmentControls[index].get('designation')!.value }}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5dgwem?file=src/app/app.component.html)